# Value at position X in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference Value could not be determined statically

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to use angular phone number in a simple project ,

this is the example that I'm trying to follow:

the second example : https://edupala.com/how-to-add-angular-phone-number-format/

I run the following code in terminal:

```
npm i ngx-mat-intl-tel-input --save
npm install libphonenumber-js --save
```

but when I try to add the NgxMatIntlTelInputModule to the imports array in the app.module file it is giving the following error:

```
Value at position 6 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference
Value could not be determined statically.
```

I'm using angular 14 .

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this that was fixable through a re installation of the module at "X" index through:

```js
npm uninstall module-name-at-index-X
```

You can determine which module is to blame by looking at the @NgModule imports array in app.module.ts (if you have decent syntax highlighting, it'll be the only module in the array that's a different color).

```js
npm install module-name-at-index-X
```

It didn't work when deleted the whole node_modules folder manually, then re installing through a regular npm install, but when I acted only on the faulty module it resolved the issue.